# Can I populate GET requests safely?

Tags: url, get, dns

I am adding random get requests to URLs.

```
foo.com/?boofoo=foo
```

Can I do this safely?  Or is is possible I might break a site by doing this?

Comment: Are you asking whether random sites on the internet have bugs?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you handle the input properly.

So for example with PHP:

```
<?php
if($_GET['booofooo'] == "value1") {
    // do something
} elseif($_GET['booofooo'] == "value2") {
    // do something
} elseif($_GET['booofooo'] == "value3") {
    // do something
} else {
    // error
}
?>
```

Also, make sure to use escape the data if you're going to put it in your database.